# An electron moving in a vacuumed chamber

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider an object of mass $m$, e.g. an electron, moving in a straight line with constant non-relativistic velocity $\vec{v}$ in a vacuumed chamber, such that there are no collisions. Imagine the chamber as a sphere of radius $r$, and while the electron is exactly in the center, it rotates clockwise by an angle $\theta$ radians.

To find the point at which the electron hits the chamber, relative to the point that it would have hit if the chamber was not rotating, can I use 'simple' mechanics, i.e. without having to account for things like Coriolis force and rotating frames?

Comment: Nobody forces you to do calculations in a rotating frame. For problems like yours there seems little advantage to pick a non-inertial frame. Sometimes nature picks a rotating frame for us (like in case of Earth's surface or for purposes of orbital mechanics) and in that case it makes sense to calculate the inertial effects that come from being in that frame.

Comment: if the chamber walls are charged you have to take them into account. The gravitational force can be ignored, look at the difference of strengths http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/funfor.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in the lab frame, you can simply consider that the electron continues on its path - regardless of the motion of the sphere. But the straight path in the lab frame will look like a curved path in the frame of reference of the sphere: initially, you appear to be aiming at a point P at the surface of the sphere, but in time your "aim" seems to drift - as though you are following a curved path. From the point of view of an observer rotating with the sphere, a "fictitious force" has appeared that is pushing your electron.

If you feel like inflicting some pain on yourself, you can perform the calculation both ways and convince yourself that they give the same answer; I prefer finding the easiest solution, and calling it a day. You know the velocity and radius, so you know the time taken; that and that angular velocity of the sphere tells you what point of the wall your electron will hit.